# How can I rearrange a url path using Htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rearrange a path

the path that works is this:

```
/profile/media/<username>
```

but to be more 'friendly' I have to use:

```
/<username>/profile/media
```

Is there a way in htaccess to test if this particular url has been passed and if so, rearrange it to the manner i need?

Many Thanks

jim

This is what worked for me using the answer below

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/profile/media$ /?index.php?q=/profile/media/$1 [L,NC]
```

Basically the site a Drupal site and Drupal just does NOT like dynamic first parts of a URL whereas this is exactly what I needed for the site to work and look a little better, the Client had asked me to set it so that the path was from the users POV rather that the POV of the site

Thanks to everyone who chipped in with helpful comments

Comment: what effort have you made

Comment: I have NO idea how to rewrite a URL in htaccess

Comment: @JimmyBorofan You don't rewrite URLs with `.htaccess`, you rewrite URLs with mod_rewrite.  `.htaccess` is just a config file, and while you certain can put your rewrite directives in there, it's not what does the rewriting.  That might help you in your Googling... if you're using Apache, look for stuff on mod_rewrite.

Comment: you don't "use htaccess". You use mod_rewrite, the directives for which can be PLACED in a .htaccess file.

Comment: Sorry your are right I will edit the question, but I thought that using mod_rewrite would have been implied, I know that you would have to use that but cannot find somewhere that will show me how to do it,

Comment: @DanielA.White why -1 this? you can see I have a rep of 25 (now 24) and OBVIOUSLY have not used the site much; not all of us can spend hours here gaining a 93K+ rep. Its difficult enough to be able to use this site without rep only for others to come along an wipe it out

Comment: @Brad & Marc B, thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(profile/media)/(.+)$ /$2/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, so with a bit a messing around I realised that I should have been sending the second section without the rearrangement but as a query string, this is what worked for me

    RewriteRule ^(.+)/profile/media$ ?index.php?action=/profile/media/$1 [L,NC]

Comment: Glad to know it worked out for you after some tweaking.